# getRelation in Propel

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, propel

News:
id
name
category_id

Category:
name
If i have relation in Doctrine then i have use:

$news->getName();
$news->getCategory()->getName() or simply $news->getCategory() instead of $news->getCategoryId()

but in Propel this doesnt working. Is possible this? I must create own function in model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your schema.yml file have the correct foreign key reference for the relation between category and news? I've submitted an example below as a reference. If you use this and build your model classes the call to the relation should work just fine.

```
news:
  _attributes: { phpName: News }
  id: { phpName: Id, type: INTEGER, size: '11', primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, required: true }
  name: { phpName: Name, type: VARCHAR, size: '50', required: false }
  category_id: { phpName: CategoryId, type: INTEGER, size: '11', foreignTable: category, foreignReference: id, onDelete: cascade, onUpdate: cascade }
```